# How to store data in array in serialize form laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to store this array in serialize form but i am unable to save array in serialize form in db.Please help me. Code is given below:

```
public function save(Request $request){     
            $r_id = $request->r_id;
            $d_id = $request->d_id;
            $c_id = $request->c_id;
            $name = $request->t_name;
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'd_id' => 'required',
                'c_id' => 'required',
                'r_id' => 'required',
                't_name' => 'required'

            ]);

            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return ['code' => 400, 'status' => 'error', 'data' => $validator->errors(), 'message' => 'Validation Error.'];
            }
   
                    $data = [];
                    foreach($request->all() as $key => $value){
                        $data[] = [
                            'r_id' => $request->r_id,
                            'd_id' => $request->d_id,
                            'c_id' => $request->c_id,
                            't_name' => $request->t_name
                        ];
                        $m_test = serialize($data);
                        ModelData::create($m_test);
                    }
                    return ['code' => 200, 'status' => 'success', 'data' => $data, 'message' => 'Test Prescription save successfully.'];
                }
                

     }
```

Comment: and what field do you think you would be trying to save this to in your table?

Comment: $request->r_id,
                          $request->d_id,
                            $request->c_id,
                            't_name' these fields in a single column test_data in table

Comment: okay, no where are you specifying what field this data should be assigned to, check the documentation for how to call `create` on the model, as you will need an associative array to pass

Comment: Why are you looping through you can simply put your date into array as key value pair and store json form in database!

Comment: If I undestood well you need you want to be able to save data which is in array in the database and retrieve it as an array when you access a specific model attribute

Comment: If I undestood well you need you want to be able to save data which is in array in the database and retrieve it as an array when you access a specific model attribute  ----yes but how

Comment: @jandialnidhi Could you please share properties of `ModelData`?  What field contains array?

Comment: protected $fillable = ['r_id','t_name','d_id','c_id'];

Comment: from the foreach loop you have made for $request->all() it looks like you want to repeatedly save same data over different keys of $data array, serialize it & then store, but store at what table column name